Show/movie with crew of cops calling a meeting where they disarm all who enter (to secretly replace magazines with blanks)
There is this moment in a movie or a TV show where 

a crew of cops (FBI or the like) are investigating a robbery or murder - or maybe an act of treason/treachery - and they are searching for this person. 
They find out that this person is a law enforcement agent, and they call a meeting where they disarm all who enter and then talk. 
Meanwhile, every magazine is replaced with blanks, and after the meeting, three (I think) of the suspects are taken somewhere by three of the officers, and one of them shoots the officer, but since it's a blank nothing happens, and they eventually get it. 

This is the closest I can recall in my mind. I think this was on Mentalist, I'm not sure.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the year you viewed it, genre, language, country and year of production, plot locale, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

I viewed it in 2016, but it's old. Genre is obviously detective, and it still reminds me of Mentalist, something to do with profiling. I am sure it is not Dexter or Criminal Minds, country is US, language is English. I don't know John, that's all I can put together. The scene when the suspect shoots the police officer is in the parking garage. The meeting that was held reminds me of a courtroom session. That's all I have.

Thanks. This additional information will help to answer the question, and help to keep if from getting put on hold. If it does, please edit your question to include the information in your comment above.

I can confirm, that this definitively is an episode of "The Mentalist".
It is "Green Light", Season 7, Episode 6.
The meeting is indeed held in a lecture hall where they tell all members of a special DEA team, that their boss is corrupt and committed the murder. 
But this is a fake information to make the real murder feel save...
Later Lisbon, Cho and Abbott take one suspect each with them and one of them tries to murder his warden with the (unloaded) weapon...
